# Where to send email by good practice in MVC pattern

Tags: model-view-controller, web

## What is the best practice for sending emails from MVC based platform ?

Should I rather send emails from controller or model ? What is the best practice ?

One opinion is that **model should send emails**, just to keep controller slimest possible, other opinion is that **controller should send emails**, because model shouldn't have access to services.

Thanks for contribution to this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be hard pressed to find a situation where it made more sense to send an email from the Model...

Without knowing the specifics of your architecture, I'd wager that the Controller should be the one to send emails, for two reasons:

1. As you mentioned, the model shouldn't have access to services
2. The email is most likely being sent as a result of some user interaction, which puts it squarely in the domain of the Controller.